# How do I create nullable params in Bicep?

Tags: azure-bicep

In Bicep I have a module that defines an app service and sets the virtual network from a parameter like this:

```
param vNetSubnetId string

resource webApplication 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
    name: webAppName
    ...
    virtualNetworkSubnetId: vNetSubnetId
}
```

When I call the module I want to conditionally set the parameter like this:

```
param useUdVnet bool

module webApp 'web-app.bicep' = {
    params: {
        vNetSubnetId: useVnet ? vNet.outputs.vNetSubnetId : null
    }
}
```

However, that produces `Expected a value of type "string" but the provided value is of type "null | string".bicep(BCP321)`.  I guess I could do an empty string or pass in a second param of type bool, but it feels hacky.  How do I declare parameter with a nullable type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a default value for the parameter. Therefore, if you don't pass it, it will be default.

```
param vNetSubnetId string = '' // <-- default value of an empty string

resource webApplication 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
    name: webAppName
    properties: {
      virtualNetworkSubnetId: vNetSubnetId
    }
}
```

---

But I guess, you don't want to include `virtualNetworkSubnetId` property if `vNetSubnetId` is empty.

Therefore, you can do the following:

1. Define variable `webAppProperties` with required properties.
2. Combine `webAppProperties` with another object based on the value of the `vNetSubnetId`. If it's empty, use empty object, if it's not empty, set the required property `virtualNetworkSubnetId`.
3. Put it to another variable `webAppProperties`.
4. Set this variable as properties of the web application.

Solution:

```
param vNetSubnetId string

var webAppProperties = {
    // Any original properties
    httpsOnly: true
}

var webAppProperties2 = union(
    // If value is not provided (default value is "")
    empty(vNetSubnetId) ? {
        virtualNetworkSubnetId: vNetSubnetId
    } : {},
  webAppProperties)

resource webApplication 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
    name: 'webappname'
    properties: webAppProperties2
}
```

---

Keep in mind that Bicep is not executed. Bicep is just a nicely-looking DSL that is translated into ARM directly.

This is the resulting ARM template without parameter passed:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.12.40.16777",
      "templateHash": "3108081616330084540"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
      "name": "test",
      "properties": {
        "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
          "scope": "inner"
        },
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "parameters": {},
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "metadata": {
            "_generator": {
              "name": "bicep",
              "version": "0.12.40.16777",
              "templateHash": "12873781246070327025"
            }
          },
          "parameters": {
            "vNetSubnetId": {
              "type": "string",
              "defaultValue": ""
            }
          },
          "variables": {
            "webAppProperties": {
              "httpsOnly": true
            },
            "webAppProperties2": "[union(if(empty(parameters('vNetSubnetId')), createObject('virtualNetworkSubnetId', parameters('vNetSubnetId')), createObject()), variables('webAppProperties'))]"
          },
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
              "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
              "name": "webappname",
              "properties": "[variables('webAppProperties2')]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, variables are just defined as functions. They will be evaluated when ARM template will be deployed.

---

You can compile a Bicep to ARM template on your local machine without deployment. Just use `bicep` CLI.

```
bicep build main.bicep
```

> Useful links:
>
> - [Parameters in Bicep - Default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameters#default-value)
> - [String functions for Bicep - "empty"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-string#empty)
> - [What is Bicep?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview?tabs=bicep)
> - [Install Bicep tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/install)

Comment: That's a really cool solution.  I learned a ton from this answer, thank you.